# Acessing Axes of 1-dim subplots as 2-d

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a function that draws a 3x3 graph table of a distribution function that takes 2 arguments. I want to draw a 1x3 graph table if I give only 1 parameter to my distribution function. How to do it properly? (Like I can make an if statement and if I need 1x3 then call ax[j].plot() but maybe there is a much more fancy way to do it)

```
def plot_distribution(distr = normal, params = {'\u03BC' : [20, 50, 100], '\u03C3\u00B2' : [0.5, 0.6, 0.8]}, name='Normal Distribution', rows=3, columns=3): 
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(rows, columns, figsize=(15, 15))
    fig.suptitle(name, fontsize=45, y=0.94)

    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(columns):
            x = np.arange(101, dtype='i')
            arg = params.values()
            ax[i][j].plot(distr(x, args(i, j, params)), color=get_color(i, j, rows), label=create_label([i, j], params))
            ax[i][j].set_xlim([0, 100])
#             ax[i][j].set_ylim([0, 1])
            ax[i][j].legend(loc='upper left')
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `np.reshape()` on our axes array: `ax = np.reshape(ax, (-1, 3))`

```
def plot_distribution(distr = normal, params = {'\u03BC' : [20, 50, 100], '\u03C3\u00B2' : [0.5, 0.6, 0.8]}, name='Normal Distribution', rows=3, columns=3): 
rows = 3 ** (len(params.values()) - 1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(rows, columns, figsize=(15, 5 * rows))
fig.suptitle(name, fontsize=45, y=0.99)
ax = np.reshape(ax, (-1, 3))

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        x = np.arange(101, dtype='i')
        arg = params.values()
        ax[i][j].plot(distr(x, args(i, j, params)), color=get_color(i, j, columns), label=create_label([i, j], params))
        ax[i][j].set_xlim([0, 100])
        # ax[i][j].set_ylim([0, 1])
        ax[i][j].legend(loc='upper left')
```